# Errors installing Magento2

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the Magento2 installer on my dev host (apache running on :8080

It's a fresh clone of the dev alpha rev 99. Oddly, I installed an earlier rev (alpha85) a few weeks back and it installed first time, no errors. That instance has since been completely deleted and mysql db instance replaced with a fresh one.

Previously, the install ran under the /pub directory. Pointing to that now creates an infinite redirect and fails. Running at xxx:8080/ causes the error below.

PHP version is 5.5.14, running through a MAMP stack.

Perhaps I deleted my common sense at the same time. Any pointers as to what is missing in my environment or other embarrassingly obvious oversights are greatly appreciated.

```
Application is not installed yet.
#0 /Volumes/Magento CE Dev/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(202): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->assertInstalled()
#1 /Volumes/Magento CE Dev/magento2/index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#2 {main}
```

Comment: I am also struggling with an issue when try to install alpha99 with composer. When try to install. It shows a blank page. Url is `my.domain.com/htdocs/setup`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to pre release version, more info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install system changed starting alpha-96 (or 97).
In order to install Magento 2 you should follow these steps.

- Get the code from github (git clone or get the archive).
- Let's say you want to install it under the folder `magento2`. put the files on your machine under DOCUMENT_ROOT/magento2.
- run `composer install` in magento2/setup
- call in browser `127.0.0.1:8080/magento2/setup` (use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost)
- run the install wizard.  Make sure that in the database settings step you test the connection to your db. If you get it wrong you're in trouble. [There is a bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/689) (at least it looks to me like one)
- The install process could take a while so sit back. You may open a beer or 2 until it's done.

That's it. Now it should work.
If you want the install to move faster you can use [this sample data](https://github.com/tzyganu/m2-sample-data). It is not an official sample data. I made it by porting the sample data from ce-1.6 to 2.0. but it seams to work for me.